# how to read <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'> file using gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")

Tags: python, django, excel, pywin32, win32com

I have been trying to read inmemory file using win32com.client named EnsureDispatch. but it gives error like this  "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find USER_FILE.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)".

But if I give the proper local file path then it is able to read.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch, gencache
import pythoncom
import time
import os
import io

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
myxlsx = gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
myxlsx.Visible = 1
myxlsx.Workbooks.Open(tmp_file)  # tmp_file is the InMemoryUploadedFile which is uploaded by django rest # #framework api
```

above code is giving error as mentioned above.
but if i give the local file path then it works fine as below

local_path = "myexcel.xlsx"

myxlsx.Workbooks.Open(local_path)

now I dont want to save file in my local as there will be 100th s of users who will be uploading the file.
how can I read that inmemory file using win32.com.
please help if any better solution is available.

Thanks in advance.